# using a JS blur to bring focus to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, blur

Sorry I'm just getting into JS functions but we have a search box on our page and when the call is made (i think its using ajax) it populates the search data into the div. We used to use jquery live search.

Within the search query we have a number of link which have a class, this class relates to a jquery modal. The older version used to work using a blur function. I am trying to port the functionality over to the new search.

What we used to have...

The jquery search:

```
         <form method="post" action="<? echo constructurl($platform_name,"https") ?>/process/feedbackcreateuser" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-right">


    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Enter your idea or feedback ... " name="title..." style="width:100%; " value="<? echo $captchamessage ?>">
    <div id="jquery-live-search" style="display:none;"></div>

    <script src="<? echo $asset_url ?>/3rdparty/feedback/jquery.liveSearch.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery('input[name="q"]').liveSearch({url: '<? echo constructurl($platform_name,"https")?>/process/searchfeedbackuser/?c=<? echo $id ?>&q='});
    </script>       

</form>
```

The JS that made it work:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- this allows search results to have same js functions -->
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("input[name='q']").blur(function() { 
$("div#jquery-live-search [rel='clickover']").clickover({ html : true} ); 
$("div#jquery-live-search input, div#jquery-live-search textarea").placeholder();
$("div#jquery-live-search .dialog-iframe-card").dialog2IFrame(  { 
            height:900,
              closeOnOverlayClick: true, 
              closeOnEscape: true, 
              removeOnClose: true, 
              showCloseHandle: true,
}); 
$("div#jquery-live-search .dialog-iframe-report").dialog2IFrame(    { 
            height:900,
              closeOnOverlayClick: false, 
              closeOnEscape: true, 
              removeOnClose: true, 
              showCloseHandle: true,
}); 
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

What we have now ...

the JS search (not jQuery anymore)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form form').submit(function(){
            $('#content').load('<? echo constructurl($platform_name,"https")?>/process/searchfeedback/?c=<? echo $id ?>', { 'q': $('input[name="query"]').val()}).slideDown('500')                  
            return false;
        });
    });
    $(function(){
    $('form').each(function () {
        var thisform = $(this);
        thisform.prepend(thisform.find('button.default').clone().css({
            position: 'absolute',
            left: '-999px',
            top: '-999px',
            height: 0,
            width: 0


        }));
    });
});
    </script>

<div id="form">
<form class="form">


<div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:10px">
<input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Enter your idea or feedback ... "   class="feedback-search  validate[required] form-control search-main" >
  <span class="input-group-btn">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" class="btn btn-search">
</span>
</div>

</div></form>
 <form method="post" action="<? echo constructurl($platform_name,"https") ?>/process/feedbackcreate" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form"  class="form-right">
</form>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

I have been trying something similar with no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- this allows search results to have same js functions -->
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#form").blur(function() { 
$("div#content [rel='clickover']").clickover({ html : true} ); 
$("div#content input, div#jquery-live-search textarea").placeholder();
$("div#content .dialog-iframe-card").dialog2IFrame( { 
            height:900,
              closeOnOverlayClick: true, 
              closeOnEscape: true, 
              removeOnClose: true, 
              showCloseHandle: true,
}); 
$("div#content .dialog-iframe-report").dialog2IFrame(   { 
            height:900,
              closeOnOverlayClick: false, 
              closeOnEscape: true, 
              removeOnClose: true, 
              showCloseHandle: true,
}); 
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure this one out so I just popped the working JS call into the dynamic content's page, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You HTML has problems:

It doesn't appear that you have closed out your `<form class="form">` tag at all before beginning a new one.  So you have nested forms and that can't happen, so you should fix that first, since `$('form').each(function () {` isn't gonna do anything for you most likely.  Not entirely sure why you would prepend a cloned button into the form with a width=0 and height=0 and no where on the page.  Kinda seems awkward doing that.  Why not use the same button to begin with?  Why make a clone of it?

Also, you haven't added a semi-colon at the end of this line here:

`$('#content').load('<? echo constructurl($platform_name,"https")?>/process/searchfeedback/?c=<? echo $id ?>', { 'q': $('input[name="query"]').val()}).slideDown('500')`

which will give a syntax error.

You should turn javascript error reporting on in your browser to be able to see all of your jQuery/javascript errors and correct these errors one by one.  After you do that, it might even fix itself.

Also, be sure to load jQuery, since you are still using it in your coding...  Here's a good CDN for jQuery to use:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks, I closed the form tags and still have the same issue. There is a js error but its from jquery - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier jquery.js:7078
(anonymous function) jquery.js:7078
b.extend.globalEval jquery.js:7082
b.fn.extend.domManip jquery.js:9597
b.fn.extend.append jquery.js:9597
(anonymous function) jquery.js:9597
b.extend.access jquery.js:7246
b.fn.extend.html jquery.js:9597
(anonymous function) jquery.js:9597
c jquery.js:7341
p.fireWith jquery.js:7403
k jquery.js:9597
r

Comment: Thanks - I have made the updates but and not sure what to put in the blur function. everything I try seems to fail.

Comment: Also, `.clickover()` is not a function of jQuery, though I believe it's in Jquery bootstrap so you will need to make sure that Jquery bootstrapx is loaded suppose.  And you should be sure that you are loading up jQuery, since you are still using it.